# change order of the rows in a view

Tags: xpages

I have a view sorted on a column named "order". This column has just a nummeric field and is gooing from 1, 2, 3 ...
In another column I've put an up arrow.

Now when the user clicks this up arrow when he is on row for example 3, the value of the field "order" of line 3 should change in 2 and the value of the field "order" of row 2 in 3 , and the view should update in order to show the change.

With k = rowData.getColumnValue("order"); I get the value of the current row. Now how do I save the change of this row, and how do I change the value of the other row ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a View Panel or something similar that uses NotesXspViewEntries or NotesViewEntries. Those objects are read only, you can't immediately update them.

You'll need to get a handle on the NotesDocument objects for the relevant NotesXspViewEntries and modify the relevant field on them. Then you'll need to refresh the view.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a viewPanel. In a column I stored the unid of the daocument. I don't know how to save the change in the backend doc once I have the unid.

Comment: Meanwhile I found a way to do everything execpt I would like the icon to be clickable. Maybe I'll start a new question for this.